# Distinct count and look the value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a writing query for distinct count of bookings table where `like` search with `'%gov%'`, `'%federal%'`, `'%army%'` with `billto`, `shipto`, `soldto` and `enduser` fields and also a customer table where the customer should belong to US..Below is the code I have tried and the result should come up single.

```
select (select distinct count (*)
        from active_customer
        where active_customer.Country = 'US'
       ),
       (select count (distinct u.field)
        from bookings
        unpivot (field
                 for fields in (billto_name, shipto_name, soldto_name, end_user)
                 ) u
        where u.field like '%gov%' or u.field like '%federal%' or u.field like '%Army%' 
       )
```

Result:

```
4808  1105
```

Result should be combined not in separate rows/columns.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What do you mean by "combined"? Should the numbers be added?

Comment: Yes, the result should be in a single row....need to get the distinct count from bookings table either the four (billto, shipto,soldto and enduser) fields have %gov% or %federal% or %army and also the customers who belongs to US.....considering all these I need to get distinct count from bookings table...

Comment: I don't get it. The numbers are already in a single row, aren't they?

Comment: So, instead of `,` between the selects, you need to use `+`?

Answer (score 0):

If your code was working but giving you results separately Just append both columns you shall have your desired result if you still have a problem cast them as varchar then append them . example bellow

```
select (select distinct count (*)
        from active_customer
        where active_customer.Country = 'US'
       )+' '+
       (select count (distinct u.field)  
        from bookings
        unpivot (field
                 for fields in (billto_name, shipto_name, soldto_name, end_user)
                 ) u
        where u.field like '%gov%' or u.field like '%federal%' or u.field like '%Army%' 
       )
```